# Is it possible to run OCaml natively in Atom?

Tags: sublime-text-3, atom-editor

I'm using the Atom text editor with the ocaml-merlin package for formatting, which makes it look nice.

However, what I really want is to be able to compile and run OCaml code directly in Atom, with an interactive Terminal where I can run functions.

I've been copy-pasting my OCaml into Terminal with utop, which is okay but it gets really tedious whenever I need to change something or if I have a long file. Is there any Atom package that allows me to run an interactive session right in Atom after compiling the code, or is there a different editor that supports this?

I am on macOS, and I have OCaml installed natively with OPAM.